# Selecting rows that don't exist physically in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've totally rewritten my question because the simplicity of the previous one people were taking too literally.

The aim:

```
INSERT INTO X
SELECT TOP 23452345 NEWID()
```

This query should insert 23452345 GUIDs to the "X" table. actually 23452345 means just any possible number that is entered by user and stored in database.

So **the problem** is that inserting rows to a database by using

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
```

statement requires you to already have the required amount of rows inserted to database.

Naturally you can emulate the existence of rows by using temporary data and cross joining it but this (in my stupid opinion) creates more results than needed and in some extreme situations might fail due to many unpredicted reasons. I need to be sure that if user entered extremely huge number like 2^32 or even bigger the system will work and behave normally without any possible side effects like extreme memory/time consumption etc...

Comment: @Denis Yaremov: why would you do that? Also, can't you do it in code, than save the results to the database?

Comment: I have a config value "BranchCount" stored in "Objectives" table, also I have the "Branches" table which sores branches which in turn tied up to other database entities. If someone will add an objective with 77777 branches I have to create exactly 77777 branches, etc... So I would like to do that in one SP I need more or less simple and stable solution because the insert is around 40 lines of SQL code... It includes INSERT INTO ... SELECT (MANY NESTED SELECTS AND JOINS AND ROW_NUMBER OVER ...) And so I need a solution that is more or less simple to integrate to my INSERT statement

Comment: You database would probably work better if you inserted 2^32 rows in separate batches anyway.  You are not going to get away from doing some logic when trying to insert a random number of rows in the database.  You can simply use a while loop and insert either 10000 rows at a time into the table (using the Integers method :)  ) or however many rows are left.

Comment: Yeah I'm left to think that the while loop is the only non-quirk solution for this problem... :(

Comment: Just because the requirement is to create 77,777 branches doesn't mean you have to actually create 77,777 physical rows all with the same default and/or nulls excpet for a GUID. Consider that when you create a new Excel worksheet and see 65536 rows it doesn't mean 65536 rows of data have actually been created under the covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all fairness I derived the idea from [this site](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/74519/SQL-list-of-numbers-1-100).

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 1 x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE x < 100
)
SELECT NEWID()
FROM cte
```

EDIT:

The general method we're seeing is to select from a table that has the desired number of rows.  It's hackish, but you can create a table, insert the desired number of records, and select from it.

```
create table #num
(
   num int
)

declare @i int
set @i = 1
while (@i <= 77777)
begin
    insert into #num values (@i)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

select NEWID() from #num

drop table #num
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Sadly it can only go up to 32,767 rows and only if you add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION  32767)`

Comment: Nice solution, better than the hacky "join to some table and fake it" approach.

Answer (score 3):

Of course creating a Number table is the best approach and will come in handy. You should definitely have one at your disposal.  If you need something as a one-off just join to a known table. I usually use a system table such as spt_values:

```
declare @result table (id uniqueidentifier)
declare @sDate datetime

set @sDate = getdate();
;with num (n)
as  (   select top(777777) row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
        from   master..spt_values t1 
        cross join master..spt_values t2
    )
insert into @result(id)
    select newid()
    from    num;
select datediff(ms, @sDate, getdate()) [elasped]
```

Comment: Yeah :) now I see what I have done, people are taking things as literal as possible, it was my mistake...

Comment: This is able to create 777777 rows twice as fast as the proposed cte solution can create 32767

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an integers table and use it.  This type of table comes in handy many situations.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Integers 
( 
    i INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
) 

WHILE COALESCE(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 0) <= 100000 /* or some other large value */
BEGIN 
    INSERT dbo.Integers DEFAULT VALUES 
END
```

Then all you need to do it:

```
SELECT NEWID()
FROM Integers
WHERE i <= 77777
```

Comment: Your approach is a breath of fresh air, but it is also can be dangerous to a client, if the number is high enough

Comment: The Integers table should be static (created once) in the database; not for each request.  (Let me know if this was not what you were referring to.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with
   L0 as (select 1 as C union all select 1)       --2 rows
  ,L1 as (select 1 as C from L0 as A, L0 as B)    --4 rows
  ,L2 as (select 1 as C from L1 as A, L1 as B)    --16 rows
  ,L3 as (select 1 as C from L2 as A, L2 as B)    --256 rows
select top 100 newid() from L3
```

Comment: (Just to get around joining to another dummy table)

Comment: Michael unfortunately this approach doesn't suit requirements, either there will be not enough rows it will generate to many rows. Is there a standard way of generating dummy rows?

Comment: @Denis sure it does just add two more CTEs to get up to 2^32 rows and then add `select TOP 77777 newID()  from L5` to get the output you're looking for

Comment: Conrad is right. Extend to two or three more levels. If you want to select with a configurable number, replace "100" with a variable "(@requiredNum)". I don't understand your last comment. It will work as long as you need.

Comment: This also has the advantage of not using any more resources than needed (because of the top operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 NEWID() from sys.all_columns
```

Or any other datasource that has a large number of records. You can build your own table for 'counting' functionality as such, you can use it in lieu of while loops.

[Tally tables: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!